# Alternative to "out" and "ref"

Tags: c#, ref, out

I have multiple functions from which i output last errors.

In c++, you can just pass a nullptr default initializer in the function prototype and it compiles fine, but in C# it doesn't seem to allow you to initialize `out` or `ref` parameters in case you do not need to use them.

There are of course plenty of answers to my question, such as just storing them within the class and such, but for my purposes, passing it from the function itself would be the prefered way.

So is there any way to have an `out` or `ref`-like parameter to a function and be able to initialize it to default values in case the user does not want to use it?

Perhaps you can use the c++ syntax somehow? (the pointers and byrefs, maybe using unsafe code?)

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Are you looking for [discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards#calls-to-methods-with-out-parameters)?

Comment: For `out`, overload the method and use `out _`.

Comment: Are you trying to perform some sort of validation when you call these functions? And then pass the validation result/error out?

Comment: Now that I think of it, this has the smell of trying to wrangle a C++-ism into C#... Can you show us some example code?

Comment: @openshac Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted to do, and it seems that Damien's and AKX's answers were exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @AKX Is that even possible? I was just mentioning that it can be done in C++, but C# is not built to handle unsafe code that you could write with C++, as far as I can see from my experience

Comment: You can use reference type (class or etc), and pass it to the method. Then if you change this value in method, then the value is also updated in the parent method,  but this is bad practice. Better return object from your method with necessary fields. Something like this: public class ResultData() { public IEnumerable<string> Errors {get; set;} //any other fields... }

Comment: You can definitely initialize in c# before calling the methods.  Simple object like int you just set a value.  If you are passing a class or structure than call the constructor with "new myClass" and if you have a pointer than use IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

Comment: @tb044491 Well if it is validation you are doing and you are after validation results there are some reasonalby well recognised patterns for doing this. However they may seems slightly convoluted if you are doing a small homework assignment or just need to get a small piece of code working. Let me know if you want an example and I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a little tedious, but you could have an out-error-less overload for each function:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static int DoThing(int a, int b, out string error) {
    error = null;
    if(a > 0 && b > 0) return a * b;
    error = "Both arguments need to be > 0, so I'm just returning zero";
    return 0;
  }
  public static int DoThing(int a, int b) {
    return DoThing(a, b, out _);
  }
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(DoThing(3, 6).ToString());
  }
}
```

(Or you could consider a generic return type that wraps the actual returned value and any errors that occur along the way, maybe.)